# Sencha touch 2:  Is it necessary the knowledge in version 1 to learn version 2?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am planning to learn Sencha touch. I heard Sencha touch-2 is the latest version. So I started to looking on version 2. Still I have a confusion that, whether I should study Sencha touch 1 also?
Some of my friends said that, knowledge in version 1 will not much helpful for learning version 2 because architectures are different in both.
Could you please clarify my doubts? And as a beginner, I found it is very difficult to follow the official document? Is there any simple document to start Sencha 2..??

Any single help would be appreciated...

Thank you....

Comment: Go directly for ST2, there are a lot of difference between the two versions. When I started working on the second version, I had to learn a lot of new things that didn't exist in the first version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having been working with Sencha Touch for over one year, from Sencha Touch 1 to beta versions of Sencha Touch 2, I can make sure that you **need not to know anything** about 1.x before learning 2.x

Why?

1. Sencha Touch 1 has a **bad** MVC design. If you try to understand them, it's like you're spending one year to master Windows 98.
2. Sencha Touch 1 does not have friendly APIs. There will be many things you don't know why they must be there, and why not.
3. Sencha Touch 1 has a very poor documentation and a few example sets, while Sencha Touch 2 documentation teaches you almost everything you want to get started.
4. Optimization varies greatly between these two versions, in which (of course) Sencha Touch 2 is better.

Answer (score 3):

I started learning Sencha Touch 2 without ever having worked with ST1. I recommend you to start reading [this guide](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/getting_started) and possibly also watching [these videos](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/video).

I learned a lot by watching the code of their examples, which you can find [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/example).

You can edit the examples which are included in the guide (For example go to http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/first_app and click Code Editor). Try some things out and you'll learn ST2 pretty fast ;)